# Eclipse Force.com IDE

Tags: force.com, eclipse

I have a new pc and a lot of ongoing work in Eclipse with Force.com IDE. I need to install the same environment on my new pc but you don't seem to be able to get the Force.com IDE for eclipse anymore. Is there a way to acquire this add on? Do not have time to learn a new dev environment as I have many project currently underway with deadlines that must be met

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm):

> After October 12, 2019, support, updates, documentation, and downloads for the Force.com IDE will no longer be available.

The only way you can hope to even get a copy of it would be to copy the installed files from your current computer to the new one, and this may or may not work.

VS Code with DX actually very easy to pick up, even if you've never used it before. The Command Palette (Ctrl-Shift-P) can find the commands you want by typing, context menus are easy to use, and the tools are well-documented. You'll want to take the time to learn this new tool; we've known the Force.com IDE was going to be desupported for years now.

To get started quickly, simply follow this [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-salesforce-dx) module, you'll be up and running *today*.

Comment: No it is not easy to pick up. Reading documentation on DX is ugly. Trying to find out how to get my sandbox into DX is total and complete new learning curve that will take time to learn and delay my projects while I do so

Comment: @Ohmicron I understand how you probably feel, as I felt that same concern when I had to migrate to VS Code. However, it really is more simple than the documentation makes it out to be. The trailhead is straight-forward, and the steps themselves aren't too bad. Basically: install SFDX, install VS Code, install DX Bundle in VS, auth to your sandbox, create a new project using your package.xml (manifest file), and you're ready to start developing. The UI is actually very similar to Eclipse, too. When I get back, I'll do some pics for you.